# Convert a formula in Excel into an Array Formula without Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, worksheet-function

Question: How might it be possible in Excel to convert a formula into an [array formula](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/enter-an-array-formula-HA102809342.aspx), without using a hotkey?

### Normal Formula

[image: Normal Formula (and result)]

### Array Formula

[image: Array Formula (and result)]

Comment: I really like this question. Microsoft is inconsistent in this special regards. Every function can somehow be executed via menu - except this one

Comment: @nixda the `=max(len)` specifically?

Comment: No, @Raystafarian, he means the conversion to an array formula from a normal formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel has a number of native formulas that allow you to create/ utilise arrays, for example

```
SUMPRODUCT()
INDEX()
OFFSET()    
SUMIFS()
COUNTIFS()
AVERAGEIFS()
```

Knowing these native formulas well will allow you to avoid the CSE array formulas in most cases (if that is your aim)

For example, try this for numbered ranges:

```
=LEN(MAX(INDEX(C2:C14,,1)))
```

Furthermore, as a result of discussion below, this formula will work for all numbered and non numbered/mixed ranges:

```
=MAX(INDEX(LEN(C2:C14),,1))
```

Comment: How would you adjust that to `=max(len)`?

Comment: @Raystafarian, I've added an example to my post

Comment: That is taking the length of the maximum number, whereas the question is taking the longest length of the items in the list. Reversing it to `=max(len(index...` doesn't seem to produce the same result. Not criticizing, +1

Comment: As far as I can tell finding the length of the largest number and the largest lengthed number are equal - I hope! The reason I used LEN(MAX(INDEX.. is because MAX() is a function that takes arrays but LEN() doesn't. Therefore if you write it the other way you would need to enter it as an array. Thanks for +1!

Comment: For this application, yes it's the same. But dealing with non-number lists, you'd need the lengths before you could find the max(number)

Comment: Curiously, you could write the formula like this, though `=MAX(INDEX(LEN(C2:C14),,1))` this will address non-number lists

Comment: You should add that to the answer, that is pretty curious. And it works with non-numbers AND mixed lists!

Comment: Thanks @CallumDS33. I asked this question on Friday, so I didn't test your solution until I got into work today -- hence the delay in accepting it. FYI, this question was a result and a part of a solution to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/813742/alphanumeric-sorting-in-excel/813773

Answer (score 1):

One work-around for this limitation is to create a small VBA Sub, and assign it to a keyboard shortcut of your choice

This will convert the selected range into an array formula.

```
Sub ConvertToArrayFormula()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    For Each arr In rng.Areas
        arr.FormulaArray = arr.Cells(1, 1).Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Good thought in general, but despite the title of my OP, I clarified my question in the post itself as "without using a hotkey?"

Substituting one hotkey for another defeats the purpose.

Now, if you can show me how to assign that Sub to a button on the toolbar -- that is just the sort of thing I'm looking for!

Comment: @MyPetOcean, was adjusting the formula not an option? You didn't explain why you need to be able to enter without using hotkey (I presume by "hotkey" you are talking about Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: I mean I'd like to avoid *any* hotkey. My initial rationale is long-term simplicity (and memorability) for non-savvy users. But secondly, there just simply *ought* to be another way to do this. What other major software has important features only accessible via hotkey of all things?

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to develop your solutions using Names for both Ranges and Formulas.

Thus, the look of your formula may be improved by defining 'v' to refer to =C2:C14. The formula =MAX(LEN(v)) still needs to be array entered but, if you define 'n' to refer to =LEN(v), the array calculation is carried out as the default behaviour of a named formula.  Therefore =MAX(n) works without using CSE entry.

Comment: For people unfamiliar with using names ranges, it would be helpful to expand your answer a little to include a simple example of how to do it.