# Excel 2016: sorting different than what expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Let's say I have filled a given column with values that contain text followed by numeric values. Whenever I try to sort the values (smallest to largest), I get the following result:

1. Picture 1
2. Picture 10
3. Picture 11
4. Picture 12
5. Picture 2
6. Picture 20
7. Picture 21
8. Picture 22
9. Picture 3

And so on and so forth. I would have expected the result to be like the following (and that is what I would like to achieve):

1. Picture 1
2. Picture 2
3. Picture 3

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alphanumeric sorting in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/813742/alphanumeric-sorting-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column and write the following formula :
**=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1))**

A1 is where **picture 1** column starts and drag it down, it will give you the numeric part of **picture 1**, and sort by this new column while selecting all data.
If you have - or any other sign instead of one blank replace it with " " for example write "-" in the formula
**Update**
If you have more than one blank in the name count the length of the name before the last blank and change 1 in Find to the length you have, in that case the formula will see the last blank only like **code picture form 1**  use

**=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,17))**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I haven't fully understood what to do. If I have, for example, a cell with the following value: `code`Picture - Flower - 1`code`, how do I implement it in the formula you have mentioned?

Comment: If you have blank before the number no need to do anything the formula will work but if no blank like Picture-Flower-1 you need to replace " " with "-" but when you have a lot of blanks you have to change the 1 in Find to 18 to skip the beginning and find the last blank

Comment: depending on your data, I have seen needing to add a +0 to Sam's equation. This helps ensure that it is treated as a number and not text .. To use Sam's answer, you will need to convert the data to a table or to expand the area being sorted to include the # column, and then sort on the # column

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tried to implement the suggested solution to the best of my knowledge, but with no success, I would appreciate if you could simply your solution for Excel dummies. I would like to note however that the solution has to allow me to continuously sort my table by other columns as well, and then sort by the alphanumeric column again. If the solution works for a one-time sort only it is not satisfactory.